# Вырезка числового значения до (после) символа ":"

Tags: php, html, парсер

Делаю парсинг текста. Текст представляет из себя Ip-адреса и порты. Мне нужно получить каждые Ip-адреса и порты в отдельности, чтобы их потом сохранить отдельно в базу.

Примерно:

```
192.168.100.1:5875

192.168.100.43:888

192.8.1.1:875

192.8.1.1:55585

10.10.10.10:5

147.2.53.256:8547
```

Как в php можно вывести ip-адрес отдельно, а порты отдельно?

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Зачем минусовать человека?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list($ip, $port) = explode(':', '192.168.100.1:5875')
echo $ip;
echo $port;
```

[explode — Разбивает строку с помощью разделителя](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)