# Как разделить строковую переменную, разделенную двоеточием, на два числа?

Tags: python, строки, int

Например, "05:08".

```
h = "05:08"
#h1 = "05" так должно быть и h2 = "08"
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вырезка числового значения до (после) символа ":"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513073/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: @DiMithras там php, тут python

Answer (score 6):

Просто указываете для `split` параметр двоеточие:

```py
h = "05:08"
h1, h2 = h.split(':')
print(h1, h2)
# 05 08
```